# Eclipse for Android: How to automate 'Export Android Application' to apk?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working an android project using eclipse. I can't test it out in emulator because of the sensor and so I have to export to APK file quite frequently. The problem is that it takes more than 10 mouse clicks and entering the (same) password two times (which I often type wrong) to generate the APK file.

I'm wondering if there is a way to automate these steps. or is there a command line equivalent for those steps?

Comment: Hi Please Check below links how to debug app in your actual device. [link1][1] [link2][2] [1]:http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/getting-started-with-android-development [2]:http://thompsonng.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-debug-with-hardware-device-in.html Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want the APK file for testing only then you can use unsigned APK.

```
Right Click Project -> Android Tools -> Export Unsigned Application Package
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is this some plug-ins? But I cannot find this option?

Answer (score 1):

if you need .apk , you should find it in project folder bin directory ,after run your application.

Comment: I just tried it and somehow this APK file cannot be installed on my Galaxy S.