# Eclipse remember Android keystore password?

Tags: android, eclipse, keystore

Without using ANT, is there a way to have Eclipse not prompt me for my keystore password (twice!) everytime I do a release build of my Android app (I use the export wizard)?

p.s.-My development PC is located inside area-51, behind several physical and virtual safeguards, so please no comments on security of stored passwords.

Comment: Not really, no.. not any more than entering my password each time I use any websites like this one, or my bank, or social media sites, but all of those have a "keep me signed in" option, so was hoping this did too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Export option is intended for signing your app with a release key, which most people will only want to do when creating a release candidate and then uploading to the Android Market.

If you are developing an app then you should probably be using the debug options to do this.

Have a look at this answer:
[Eclipse for Android: How to automate 'Export Android Application' to apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162450/eclipse-for-android-how-to-automate-export-android-application-to-apk)

Comment: Marked as answer, because it is the best answer when the real answer is mostly like "not possible" or "not worth the effort to make possible" because nobody else is doing things this way.  Call me crazy but I've always prefered testing with as "close to the real thing" as possible -- at least once I'm beyond my own debugging and giving updates to my test department.

Comment: I agree - I've also got into the habit of exporting the release version of one of my apps for testing, and entering the password each time is rather tedious!

Comment: if you are using google maps you have no choice but to sign your apps.. not a good answer